# Woocommerce Cart rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-rest-api

I am facing the issue to update the persistent cart in my WooCommerce cart API when I am update product into the cart by rest api. it is not displayed in my website . and when I am adding the product from the website in the API I will get the product but  when adding the product from API the website cart is overridden by the API cart products

my rest api code :

```
if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    $cart = WC()->instance()->cart;
    if ( woo_in_cart( $product_id ) ) {
        $cart_id      = $cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
        $cart_item_id = $cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );
        $cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_id, $quantity );
    } else {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
    }

} else {
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
}
if ( ! empty( $user_id ) ) {
    $full_user_meta['cart'] = WC()->cart->get_cart();;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1', $full_user_meta );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating `woocommerce_persistent_cart_1` is not enough, you have to replace/update the session cart data present in `wp_woocommerce_sessions` table specific to **user id** too.